# Conditional "assignment" in functional programming

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I am programming something that doesn't have side-effects, but my code is not very readable.
Consider the following piece of code:

```
(let [csv_data (if header_row (cons header_row data_rows) data_rows)]
)
```

I'm trying to use `csv_data` in a block of code. What is a clean way of conditioning on the presence of a `header_row`? I've looked at `if-let`, but couldn't see how that could help here.

I have run into similar situations with functional for-loops as well where I'm binding the result to a local variable, and the code looks like a pile of expressions.

Do I really have to create a separate helper function in so many cases?
What am I missing here?

Comment: My answer was wrong, so I've deleted it meantime.

Comment: Well, I think there was only a small mistake, but it was otherwise a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use underscore, prefer dashes.

Second, there is nothing wrong with a little helper function; after all, this seems to be a requirement for handling your particular data format.

Third, if you can change your data so that you can skip those decisions and have a uniform representation for all corner cases, this is even better. A header row contains a different kind of data (column names?), so you might prefer to keep them separate:

```
(let [csv {:header header :rows rows}]
  ...)
```

Or maybe at some point you could have "headers" and "rows" be of the same type: sequences of rows. Then you can concat them directly.
The `ensure-x` idiom is a very common way to normalize your data:

```
(defn ensure-list [data]
  (and data (list data)))
```

For example:

```
user=> (ensure-list "something")
("something")
user=> (ensure-list ())
(())
user=> (ensure-list nil)
nil
```

And thus:

```
(let [csv (concat (ensure-list header) rows)]
  ...)
```

Comment: 1. Are there any historical reasons as to why Clojure prefers dashes?

2. I am doing an export of data, so I have to merge everything and pass it to a lib.

Comment: @m33lky (1) Dash-separated symbols come from Lisp; this is just a convention  like you can find in other languages. (2) Maybe at some point you could have "headers" and "rows" be of the same type: sequences of rows. Then you can concat it directly. I agree that pushes the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @m33lky [Clojure style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide) recommends **"lisp-case"** for variable names (since Clojure is a lisp dialect).  The reason lisp uses dashes rather than underscore appears to be historical based upon the difficulty of typing dash vs. underscore on early lisp terminals [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900342/why-is-the-hyphen-conventional-in-symbol-names-in-lisp)

Comment: @coredump I'm using [clojure.data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv/blob/2a4b8a365b1a3dabe4c9b5455c2b33523fcef559/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/csv.clj#L127) which takes as input rows in a sequence, but I still don't see how I can concatenate a null header nicely.

Comment: @m33lky concat works with sequences. Maybe I am missing something, but here is a simple example: http://pastebin.com/raw/b3FP6DHg

Comment: @coredump I see it now. Just use an empty seq for header_row instead of null. This is probably how it's meant to be used, so I'll assign the solution to you.

Comment: `nil` puns into an empty sequence, so `ensure-list` is redundant on `()`: `(concat nil [3 4 5])` => `(3 4 5)`; `(cons :s nil)` => `(:s)`;  `(conj nil :s)` `(:s)`. And `list?` is a fragile test in Clojure: most sequences are something else: lazy sequences or conses or whatever. Try `sequential?` instead.

Comment: @Thumbnail I know nil acts as an empty sequence in concat but I don't get what you are saying about nil being redundant. I can't use sequential? here because a header_row might be a sequence itself (e.g. multiple column names). In fact I changed ensure-list so that it is closer to the original test made by OP in the question: wrap in a list anything that is not nil, so that concat works for any value taken by header.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `cond->>` macro

```
(let [csv_data (cond->> data_rows
                 header_row (cons header-row)]
   )
```

It works like the regular `->>` macro, but before each threading form a test expression has to be placed that determines whether the threading form will be used.

There is also `cond->`. Read more about threading macros here: [Official threading macros guide](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros)

Comment: While I can see how this is idiomatic advanced Clojure I find it a bit hard to read. The semantics are quite loaded: "Note that unlike its relatives, some-> or cond, cond-> never short-circuits evaluation, even if a test evaluates to false or nil". Also, there was an answer involving cond-> posted here and there was a mistake. I attribute it to cognitive load. I understand the value of macros, but here it feels heavy to me.

Comment: @m33lky Short-circuiting does not affect your question. It just means that if you have multiple test/form pairs one falsy test won't affect the other pairs. This is in no way a "heavy" macro or advanced Clojure. It reads quite simply: Take data_rows, if there is a header_row, cons the header_row. Of course you have to learn the syntax for a macro to be able to read it. Consider macros like case, cond, defn etc. Macros are syntax to be learned.

Comment: I meant to say that it's for an advanced Clojure programmer. I have personally never used this particular macro. While it is easy to learn this new functionality, I think it takes experience in order to be able to "read" such logic with the same speed and confidence as the more traditional constructs like if/cond. Do you agree that a cond->> is much heavier than a cond? It's a bit of an unfair comparison, since the use cases are different.

Comment: No, it's just more uncommon in other languages/idioms than `cond`.  That's why it might seem off-putting at first. You don't need tough experience though to read it, you just need to learn it. I wrote it three times or so, than I read it like any other code.

Answer (score 1):

i would propose an utility macro. Something like this:

```
(defmacro update-when [check val-to-update f & params]
  `(if-let [x# ~check]
     (~f x# ~val-to-update ~@params)
     ~val-to-update))

user> (let [header-row :header
            data-rows [:data1 :data2]]
        (let [csv-data (update-when header-row data-rows cons)]
          csv-data))
;;=> (:header :data1 :data2)

user> (let [header-row nil
            data-rows [:data1 :data2]]
        (let [csv-data (update-when header-row data-rows cons)]
          csv-data))
;;=> [:data1 :data2]
```

it is quite universal, and lets you fulfill more complex tasks then just simple consing. Like for example you want to reverse some coll if check is trueish, and concat another list...

```
user> (let [header-row :header
            data-rows [:data1 :data2]]
        (let [csv-data (update-when header-row data-rows
                                    (fn [h d & params] (apply concat (reverse d) params))
                                    [1 2 3] ['a 'b 'c])]
          csv-data))

;;=> (:data2 :data1 1 2 3 a b c)
```

**update**
as noticed by @amalloy , this macro should be a function:

```
(defn update-when [check val-to-update f & params]
  (if check
     (apply f check val-to-update params)
     val-to-update))
```

Answer (score -1):

After thinking about the "cost" of a one-line helper function in the namespace I've came up with a local function instead:

```
(let [merge_header_fn   (fn [header_row data_rows] 
                          (if header_row 
                            (cons header_row data_rows) 
                            data_rows))
      csv_data (merge_header_fn header_row data_rows) ]
  ...
  <use csv_data>
  ...
)
```

Unless someone can suggest a more elegant way of handling this, I will keep this as an answer.

Comment: I don't see an improvement here, the inlined version is more readable IMHO. Also, what is the "cost" you are talking about? Old reference but still relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.lang.lisp/9SKZ5YJUmBg/Fj05OZQomzIJ

Comment: Too much happening in one line. There is also a lack of structure.

Comment: I often make local helper functions like this if they will not be used outside of the local context (I modified your formatting a bit for ease of reading). Whether local in a `let` expression or top-level in a `def` expression, there is no "cost" one way or the other.  As always, making the code simple, obvious, and correct outweigh any other worries.

Comment: Well, I think it's clear that I'm trying to make an assignment similar to how you would do it in an imperative language. There is little significance of this piece of code by itself, and that's why I feel it doesn't deserve to be outside the local scope and clutter the namespace. Why the downvote?